# jQuery Change Background Position Using Relative Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I am trying to change the image background position X & Y using relative values (+= and -=) when click on the button. It seems to reset itself to 0% 0%. It didnt work.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f2pf/)

```
$(function(){
 $("body").on("click", "#move", function() {            
    $("#obj-1").css({ 'backgroundPosition': '+=0px -=5px' });             
    return false;
 });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the click function as below:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click","#move", function(){
        var backgroundPos = $("#obj-1").css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
        var xPos = parseInt(backgroundPos[0], 10);
        var yPos = parseInt(backgroundPos[1], 10);
        var newX = xPos + 0;
        var newY = yPos - 5;
        $('#obj-1').css({
  'background-position':newX+'px '+newY+'px'
});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaasthana/8f2pf/9/). hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now on click image will shift from top and left to 10px eveyrtime.

here is the updated jquery code.

```
$(function(){
 $("body").on("click","#move", function(){
        $("#obj-1").css({
            left: $("#obj-1").position().left + 10 + "px",
            top: $("#obj-1").position().top + 10 + "px"
        }); 
 return false;
 });
})
```

Here is the working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/8f2pf/7/

Comment: It's the background position not the actual object position. Left and Top CSS values already work.